# Windows cmd & PowerShell redirect to file doesn't work

Tags: c, powershell, cmd, yacc

I have an executable that receives as an argument a file which it tires to parse and translate it to ASM x86 (FLEX + YACC).

The thing is that I'm trying to make a script which parses a bunch of files and creates the ASM output files and apparently the file redirect doesn't work but writing the output on the screen does.

With cmd:

```
.\mmlp.exe .\in\2.ps1
```

The result on stdout:

```
bits 32
global start

; Needed procedures
extern exit, scanf, printf

; Imports
import exit msvcrt.dll
import scanf msvcrt.dll
import printf msvcrt.dll

; Data segment
segment data use32 class=data

    ; Format used by scanf & printf
    format_d db "%d", 0

    ; Program's variables

    x dd 0
; Code segment
segment code use32 class = code
start:

    ; WRITE TO STDOUT
    push dword x
    push dword format_d
    call [printf]
    add esp, 4 * 2

    ; exit(0)
    push dword 0
    call [exit]
```

but if I try this:

```
.\mmlp.exe .\in\2.ps1 > some-file.asm
```

the file will be empty.

The same goes with PowerShell, tried different approaches, none worked

```
& $exePath @($inFile) | Out-File some-file.asm
or
$result = & $exePath @($inFile)
or
& "cmd.exe" @("/c", $exeFile, $inFile, ">", "some-file.asm")
```

Nothing works, the file is still empty.
I even tried capturing all the output streams, but the same result.

The main function in the yacc file is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc == 2) {
        yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
    else {
        yyin = stdin;
    }

    asm_segment_data = malloc_list();
    asm_segment_code = malloc_list();

    int yyparse_result = yyparse();

    reverse_list(asm_segment_data);
    reverse_list(asm_segment_code);
    struct list_node *current;
    printf("%s%s", ASM_FILE_HEADER, ASM_SEGMENT_DATA);
    for(current = asm_segment_data->root; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        printf("%s", current->value);
    }
    
    printf("%s", ASM_SEGMENT_CODE);
    for(current = asm_segment_code->root; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        printf("%s", current->value);
    }

    printf("%s", ASM_EXIT);

    free_list(asm_segment_data);
    free_list(asm_segment_code);
    return yyparse_result;
}
```

Basically, I have a bunch of printf's.

I'm thinking of giving a second parameter and writing to that file, but somewhat I like this approach more since it gives me more flexibility.
Clearly, I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see what.

UPDATE: this is how I compile my executable (PowerShell):

```
$yaccFileNameFullPath = Join-Path -Path $WorkingDir -ChildPath $YaccFileName
& "bison" @("-y", "-d", $yaccFileNameFullPath)
$flexFileNameFullPath = Join-Path -Path $WorkingDir -ChildPath $FlexFileName
& "flex" @($flexFileNameFullPath)
& "gcc" @("lex.yy.c", "y.tab.c", "-o", $exeFullPath)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I tried everything recommended in the comments, using fprintf(stdout...) instead of just printf but that didn't work. The extension of the file doesn't matter, tried with a bunch of them. The name is basically just a word and a number [example1.extension].

I ended up and just added another parameter which represents the path t the output file. Opened that file and wrote to it with fprintf, still nothing.

Somehow I ended up commenting out these lines, which in turn succeeded in the operation of writing to file.

```
    // free_list(asm_segment_data);
    // free_list(asm_segment_code);
```

the free_list function:

```
void free_list(struct list *list)
{
    struct list_node *current;
    for (current = list->root; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        free(current);
    }

    free(list);
}
```

Why having a memory leak in the end works? I get that I'm freeing the allocated char arrays, but shouldn't printf/fprintf write a copy? Is that memory somehow linked? I should free after I flush/close the file?

This is how I'm allocating the memory for the list_node values

```
#define ASM_FORMAT_ASSIGNMENT "\
    ; ASSIGNMENT\n\
    mov AX, [%s]\n\
    mov [%s], AX\n\n\
"

char *asm_assignment(char *from, char *to)
{
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc((strlen(ASM_FORMAT_ASSIGNMENT) +
                                   strlen(from) +
                                   strlen(to) + 1) *
                                  sizeof(char));
    sprintf(buffer, ASM_FORMAT_ASSIGNMENT, from, to);
    return buffer;
}
```

and then later I use it inside the YACC file on a matching pattern as follows:

```
assignment          : ID ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR operation {
                            memmove($1, $1 + 1, strlen($1)); // Remove '$' from variable name.
                            char *buffer = asm_assignment($3, $1);
                            printf("[mmlp.y] NEW ASM_ASSIGNMENT %s\n", buffer);
                            add_list(asm_segment_code, buffer);
                        }
```

Comment: Does `2> foo` work ?

Comment: `& "cmd.exe" @("/c", $inFile, ">", "some-file.asm")` should be `& "cmd.exe" @("/c", $exeFile, $inFile, ">", "some-file.asm")` or simply `cmd /c $exeFile $inFile '>' somefile-asm`, but if neither cmd.exe nor PowerShell work, it suggests a problem with your executable. Is the output file truly empty (0 bytes)? Does anything print to the terminal when you try to redirect?

Comment: @Marged that strangely prints the output in the terminal, and creates the file empty.

Comment: @mklement0 you are right, I forgot to add that when creating the post. I'm sure that it is a problem with the executable, but I don't see what, it's just printf. The file is truly empty, and nothing gets output to the terminal, just a newline.

Comment: The filename here could matter.  Are you literally using `some-file.asm`?  Cuz `some file.asm` could be interpreted quite differently.  For something to try: `.\mmlp.exe .\in\2.ps1 > "some-file.asm"`

Comment: @Vivere, the `2> foo` result is expected: it only redirects _stderr_ output, of which there is none, while passing the _stdout_ output through to the terminal. I don't know what compiler you're using, but you could try `fprintf(stdout, ...)` instead.

Comment: @mklement0 OMG, I can't believe what was the issue. See my latest update, it's so strange.

Comment: If removing a call to `free` changes the output of a previous call to `printf`, you've got undefined behavior somewhere in your program. Either the `free` causes the UB (because the pointer you're passing to `free` no longer points to memory allocated by `malloc` for example) or the UB is there anyway and the `free` only happens to mess with `printf`'s buffer because of the UB (some memory corruption that messed with the memory you're freeing, say).